# use svn log as debian package changelog

Tags: svn, debian, package-managers, changelog

I want to use my svn log as debian/changelog file used by dpkg-buildpackage in package building.

I tried svn2cl in subversion-tools package to create a changelog from svn log but it  is not formatted as a standard debian changelog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best would be to create XSLT stylesheet and process the `svn` output to suite your needs.

```
# svn log --xml --verbose | xsltproc svn2cl.xsl - > changeLog
```

You can modify the one provided by [`svn2cl`](http://arthurdejong.org/svn/svn2cl/svn2cl-0.13/svn2cl.xsl).

Additionally, there is a script that Thomas Lange wrote available [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-fai-devel@uni-koeln.de/msg00586.html), but still I would suggest using regular XSL over a custom script.

BTW, [svn-buildpackage](http://debianpaket.de/svn-buildpackage/index.html) have this functionality build in, although it does require you to follow a very strict procedure of handling a package in SVN repo...